# Alignment vertically suffixIcon/prefixIcon in textformfield and textform in flutter

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I have tried to change TextFormField prefix icon alignment, but flutter don't have a property for this.
[image]

My code:

```
TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      style: typography.titleMedium,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isNullOrEmpty) {
          _shakeDescKey.currentState?.shake();
          return "";
        }
        bloc.onChangeDescription(value!);
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: intl.descMsg,
        hintStyle: typography.titleMedium!
            .apply(color: AppColors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
        prefixIcon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.pen),
      cursorColor: Colors.black,
      maxLines: 6,
 );
```

I need a property to align vertically prefix icon

Answer (score 2):

Wrap Icon widget in Column:

```
prefixIcon: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
               Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.pen),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution will help you , If you find another better solution, you can add it here

you will give to `prefixIcon` widget like `const SizedBox()`

and then wrap `TextFormField` with a `Stack`

and use icon as widget like below code

```
    Positioned(
          top: 21,
          right:14,
          left: 14,
             child:  SvgPicture.asset(
             your icon,
             height: 17,
             width: 17,
               ),
                  )
```

[THIS OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxt4u.png)